# How to convert letters to numbers using python

Tags: python

I want to convert the letters to numbers along with special characters and numbers remaining as it is.

Code:

```
input = raw_input('Insert the string: ');
output = [];
for character in input:
    number = ord(character) - 96;
    output.append(number);

print output;
```

I can convert the alphabets to letters, but when I input numbers, it's showing the negative numbers.

[image]

Any suggestions? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the code that is in the other IDLE window? Also, why do you want `s` to turn into `1`? what is the logic that governs what number each letter should turn into? I have a sneaky suspicion that you are subtracting 96 from the ascii value of each character to obtain the list you've shown us

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am guessing the code you are using is , from the other link you gave in the question -

```
print [ord(char) - 96 for char in raw_input('Write Text: ').lower()]
```

This , as you already found out in your example, would convert all the characters to their unicode counterparts,if you do not want want to convert numbers you can use the following -

```
>>> print ''.join([str(ord(ch) - 96) if ch.isalpha() else ch for ch in raw_input('Write Text: ').lower()])
Write Text: abcd123 @!#as1
1234123 @!#1191
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are trying to convert every alphabet in the string to it's respective positional number in the alphabet . If so, You can do this:

```
s = 'abcd123 @!#as1'
s = ''.join([(str(ord(x)-96) if x.isalpha() else x) for x in list(s)])
print(s)
```

Output:

```
1234123 @!#1191
```

Answer (score 0):

What I imagine you are looking for:

```
dat = []
for c in s:
    if(c.isalpha()):
        dat.append(str(ord(c)-ord('a') + 1))
    else:
        dat.append(c)
```